# Disable android device back button until ionic LoadingController close

Tags: angular, ionic2, loader, back-button

We are worked on ionic native mobile app.In  application have  more then 10 page.

Loader code:
//LoaderService

```
    this.loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
          content: "Loading",
          //duration: 2000,
        });
        return this.loader;
this.loader = this.LoaderService();
this.loader.present();//Loader start
his.loader.dismiss();//Loader Stop
```

Loader we are using every page .If loader is open in that time user click back button, Back button function working it's going to other page loader also going to next page .

We need if loader open back button code should stop working

Back button code
app.component.ts

```
if (this.platform.is('android')) {
        this.platform.registerBackButtonAction((e) => {
            //my code
          });
        }
```

We tried one way like put flag true while loader present.while dismiss set flag false.But we can't change every page.Give me any idea for that

Comment: I'm using this `location.onPopState(() => {
            window.history.forward();
        });` from `import { PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common';` and `private location: PlatformLocation` in the constructor. But mine is a web application not sure if it work for ionic.

Answer (score 2):

Just define avarible to store whether loading is presenting or not and wrap present and dismiss function in your service 
**LoaderService**

```
loader: any;
isShowLoading: false;
constructor(){
   this.loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
       content: "Loading",
   });
   this.loader.onDidDismiss(()=>{
        this.isShowLoading = false; //loader dismissed
    })
}

showLoading(){
    this.loader.present();
    this.isShowLoading = true;
}

hideLoading(){
    this.loader.dismiss();
    this.isShowLoading = false;
}
```

**SomeComponent**

```
this.platform.registerBackButtonAction((e) => {
     return !this.loaderService.isShowLoading
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply .In question already mention about flag true or false .Our problem is We have more then 10 pages ,now we can't change ever page with flags.